# Long time blooming hydrangea

Tags: houseplants, containers, hydrangea

I have a small garden , and i have planted a hydrangea in a large pot.But it gave me flowers for a very small time of the year. When i checked in net some one was saying ["forever and ever hydrangea"](https://www.forever-ever.eu/) are best in giving long time blooming.But i didn't find a place to buy near I live.I live in Dublin,Ireland.**Can some one help me to find a hydrangea variety that have long blooming time and suite for zone 9 ** Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Having checked, your 'forever and ever' flowering hydrangea plants are said to bloom on old and new wood, unlike the usual H. macrophylla, which might mean they repeat bloom - but not necessarily in practice, according to some forums on the web. These plants are available in the States, and are just becoming available here - the RHS was selling them, so you need to do an internet search for 'forever and ever' hydrangea for your country.

You haven't said which variety of Hydrangea you have, but you have said its in a pot. In the ground, these plants (where you are, and assuming its Hydrangea macrophylla of some variety), grown in good conditions, would normally start to bloom in June and the flowers will start to fade easily by end of July or now. In a pot, the flowers tend to last a much shorter time. Unfortunately, if you have a small garden, a hydrangea is not a good choice because of their size when planted in the ground, although H. paniculata varieties are certainly worth considering - these can at least be pruned back hard in autumn, unlike macrophylla varieties.

I'd add, though, that even with a forever and ever type, you may not get good growth and repeat flowering if the plant is not in the ground, despite their smaller ultimate size.

Comment: My plant name is Tiara hydrangea.. I start gardening this year only. So i did't actually checked its blooming period when i bought it..Now only i felt that i did't select the correct one.

Comment: Hydrangea serrata Tiara then, - its one of the smaller ones, should only be around 4 feet after ten years. I wonder if you bought it when it was in flower - that's when garden centres sell it, and other plants, when they're flowering because people are much more likely to buy then if they don't know much about plants. In a small garden, each plant needs to be chosen carefully to contribute maximum beauty - but often, beauty and colour comes from leaves, certainly over a longer time period and particularly in winter.

Comment: I really do not think 'forever and ever' is meant to mean flowers.  More than likely as I was once a florist it means you can enjoy it in the pot and plant it in your garden to bloom again next year.  All plants have periods of planned parenthood, grins and then they are done.  Done with flowering anyway.  The beauty of the foliage, shape, health is even better than the short fireworks.  Oh, there you go Bamboo, she is another foliage and healthy plant lover.  Flowers are like the tiny cherry on the top of a yummy fudge sundae.  Fun for a short while.  Other plants could be flowering...